# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)

Tags: mysql

First, I tried to connect MySql with my web project and occurred following exception.

`Unknown character set index for field '255' received from server`

So I changed explicit_defaults_for_timestamp in MySql optionsFile according to someone's advice and stopped MySql in Service tab.
After that, I tried to restart MySql in service tab or cmd, but it doesn't work.

Error: `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) (2003)`

Answer (score 1):

If mysql isn't running, you can't connect to it (duh!).

Check the logfile why it won't start.